How to prevent 504 Gateway Timeout Error using SignalR with .NET Core API and React client?
I have an endpoint that uploads a CSV into my web application to import data, and while the request succeeds a majority of the time, with bigger data sets, the client eventually times out with a 504 error. The server, however, is still importing the data into my database, so after some time the imported data will eventually be added in. The 504 ends up causing the application to show a blank white page.
I want to maintain a connection between the client and the server for as long as it takes for the request to finish and am using SignalR to attempt to do just that, but I think I'm missing something somewhere. I've been able to establish a connection and "ping" a message from the client to the server based on an interval I set on the client-side, and the server pings back a message, but I'm still getting the 504 error.
.NET Core Implementation:
Setup in Program.cs:
...

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("WebSocketsClientPermission", policy => {
            policy
                .WithOrigins("https://localhost:5001")
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowCredentials();
        });
    });

builder.Services.AddSignalR(options =>
    {
        options.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
    });


builder.Services.AddSingleton<SharedConnections>();

app.UseCors("WebSocketsClientPermission");

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        endpoints.MapHub<WebSocketHub>("/PingServer");
    });

...

SharedConnections Class:
Used to track current connections.
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

public class SharedConnections
    {
        private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, WebSocketConnection> _connections = new();

        public ConcurrentDictionary<string, WebSocketConnection> Connections => _connections;
    }

WebSocketConnection Class:
public class WebSocketConnection
    {
        public string ConnectionId { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }

WebSocketHub Class:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

public class WebSocketHub : Hub
    {
        // Used for tracking different connections.
        private readonly SharedConnections _sharedConnections;

        public WebSocketHub(SharedConnections sharedConnections) => _sharedConnections = sharedConnections;

        public async Task StartConnection(WebSocketConnection conn)
        {
            await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, conn.ConnectionId);

            // Add new connection ID to dictionary.
            _sharedConnections.Connections[Context.ConnectionId] = conn;

            await Clients.Groups(conn.ConnectionId).SendAsync("StartConnection", $"Connection {conn.ConnectionId} has started...");
        }

        public async Task PingServerWithMessage()
        {
            if(_sharedConnections.Connections.TryGetValue(Context.ConnectionId, out WebSocketConnection conn))
            {
                await Clients.Group(conn.ConnectionId).SendAsync("PingServerWithMessage", $"Pinging connection {conn.ConnectionId} from server...");
            }
        }
    }

REACT Implementation:
App.js:
...
import { HubConnectionBuilder, LogLevel } from "@microsoft/signalr"

// Set a state variable for the HubConnection.
const [webSocketConnection, setWebSocketConnection] = useState()

...

const startConnection = async (connectionId) => {
    try {
      // Initiate a connection.
      const connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                    .withUrl(`${process.env.REACT_APP_URL}`) // Variable is the application's URL + /PingServer.
                    .configureLogging(LogLevel.Information)
                    .build()

      // Set up handlers.
      connection.on("StartConnection", (message) => {
        console.log("Message:", message)
      })

      connection.on("PingServerWithMessage", (message) => {
        console.log("Message:", message)
      })

      await connection.start()
      connectionId = connectionId.toString()
      await connection.invoke("StartConnection", {connectionId})

      setWebSocketConnection(connection)
    } catch(error) {
      console.log("Error:", error)
    }
  }

From App.js I'm passing down the HubConnection object and startConnection() as props to my component that handles uploading the CSVs (only showing the relevant code):
ImportData Component:
const ImportData = ({..., webSocketConnection, startNewConnection }) => {

...

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)
  const [startPing, setStartPing] = useState(false)
  const MINUTE_MS = 5000

  // Create a random number to identify the new connection and start connection.
  useEffect(() => {
    let connectionId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000)
    startConnection(connectionId)
  }, [])

  // Use to "ping" the server.
  const sendMessage = async() => {
    try {
      await webSocketConnection.invoke("PingServerWithMessage")
    } catch(error) {
      console.error("Error:", error)
    }
  }

  // Ping the server every five seconds.
  useEffect(() => {
    if (webSocketConnection) {
      const interval = setInterval(async () => {
        await sendMessage()
      }, MINUTE_MS)
  
      return () => clearInterval(interval)
    }
    
  }, [startPing])

  const handleFileUpload = async (file) => {
  setIsLoading(true) // Show loading spinner overlay.
    ...
        try {
          // Start ping-ponging with server to keep connection open.
          setStartPing(true) // Change state to initiate pinging.
          const upload = await apiCalls.postFile(...) // API call
          setIsLoading(false) // Stop showing loading spinner overlay and return to main page.
          setTimeout(() => {
            navigate(`/main_page`)
          }, 3000)
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error:", error)
          ...
        }
      }
    } else {
      ...
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      // Executes handleFileUpload() once Submit button is pressed occurs here.
    </>
  )
}

I was thinking that as long as the websocket connection stays open and the client is receiving some response from the server, the HTTP request (apiCalls.postFile(...)) could continue to execute without the client timing out. But I'm thinking because I'm just console logging the server's response within the PingServerWithMessage handler, nothing's actually happening? Should I have some state variable that's capturing the server message and then using that to keep the connection open? I'm stuck on where to go from here and what to try cause I'm not even sure if I'm on the right track with my current solution.
To reiterate:
Problem: Client is timing out and showing a blank page while API call slowly imports data. Occurs after a minute of no response from the server in Chrome.
What I want expect to happen: API call is executed, and while that runs, client and server ping each other back and forth at some interval (currently 5 seconds) and keeps connection open until an error response is returned or an OK response, then the websocket connection should close and navigate back to the main page.


How to prevent 504 Gateway Timeout Error using SignalR with .NET Core
API and React client?

Well based on your scenario, description along with your shared code snippet it seems you've configured SignalR correctly.
However, its hard to offer you any direct or straightforward solution so your 502 timeout issue because, we need to check lot of stuffs back and forth in order to investigate the reason why its getting timeout issue.
Within your code, I have seen you have used console.log to check your latest status,  while console logging the server message helps with debugging, it doesn't keep the connection alive. You need to acknowledge the server's response explicitly.
In your PingServerWithMessage handler, instead of just logging the message, update a state variable to indicate a successful ping. This could be a boolean flag like isConnectionActive.
In addition, You could use the isConnectionActive state to conditionally render your UI. While the connection is active (during the upload), show a loading indicator or progress bar. Once the connection closes (due to error or success).
Another important thing I would like to double check that's hows your CSV upload method? Is it async operation?
Would you kindly ensure your CSV import process is handled asynchronously. Frameworks like ASP.NET Core provide libraries like Task to manage long-running operations without blocking the main thread.
Also, when you are processing the CSV, consider sending progress updates or success/failure messages through SignalR back to the client. This can further enhance the user experience by providing real-time feedback on the import process.
As I told you earlier, its really hard to offer any specific solution for your issue. Since SignalR is not specifically designed for handling long-running requests, you might still face timeouts due to network or client-side settings.
Even if you're pinging the server periodically, the underlying HTTP request might still time out. You need to ensure that the client-side timeout settings are adjusted accordingly.
Note: Please refer to this official document, which might help you to continue your investigation.
